# Getting strings in array out of a loop

Tags: c, arrays, string, loops, codeblocks

I made a loop which takes lines one by one from a test.txt file.
Inside test there is a simple non-sense text:

```
int main(int argc, char  *argv[])
{
  return abc, def;
}
```

The purpose of my program is to take it to the parts.
For example: take word "argc," and save it into array[2].

My code:

```
char break1[] = "- \t\n\0;)(";
char* array[x];
char* Buffor;
int intlength = 0;
int a=0, b=0, c=0, d=0, e=0, f=0, g=0, h=0, i=0, j=0, k=0, l=0, m=0;
FILE * File;
Plik = fopen("Test.txt", "r");
char Line[150];
while(!feof(File))
    {
        fgets(Line, 150, File);
        Buffor = strtok(Line, Break1);
        while(Buffor != NULL)
        {
            if(c==1)
            {
                array[i]=Buffor;
                printf("\n%s for %d", array[i], i);
                i++;
                b++;
                if(strstr(Buffor, ";") != NULL)
                {
                    c--;
                }
            }
            if(d==1)
            {
                if(strstr(Buffor, "return") != NULL)
                {
                array[i]=Buffor;
                printf("\n%s for %d", array[i], i);
                    c++;
                    i++;
                    b++;
                    d--;
                }
            }
            if(a==1)
            {
                array[i]=Buffor;
                printf("\n%s for %d", array[i], i);
                i++;
                b++;
                if(strstr(Buffor, ")") != NULL)
                {
                    a--;
                    d++;
                }
            }
            if(strstr(Buffor, "int") != NULL)
            {
                intlength = strlen(Buffor);
                if(intlength<5)
                {
                    array[i]=Buffor;
                    printf("\n%s for %d", array[i], i);
                    i++;
                    b++;
                    a++;
                }
            }
            Buffor = strtok(NULL, Break1);
        }
```

The problem is: strings which i want to take out from the loop (marked red) are changing to those which are marked with orange. How can i keep those in red? I tried to make it with pointers but im just not good enough...
[image]

Btw. Compiler isn't giving any errors or warning.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Question is not clear, Would you please give input output and expected output sample?

Comment: Input is this text.file which i said up:                                                                                  int main(int argc, char  *argv[])
{
  return abc, def;
}                      Output should be: array[0]= "int";     array[1]="main(int"; array[2]="argc," etc. as in picture i gave

Comment: Who or what text suggested using `feof(File)`?

Comment: Don't know. It just is. It is the only way i know. Is it possible to do what i want?

Comment: regarding these 3 lines: `while(!feof(File))
    {
        fgets(Line, 150, File);` 1) NEVER use `while( !feof( FILE ) )`  The function: `feof()` does not do what you seem to be expecting it to do.  2)  suggest: `while(  fgets( Line, sizeof( line ), File )`

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If ==NULL, then call `perror()` to output the enclosed text and the reason the system thinks the operation failed to `stderr`.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) separate code blocks ( for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default ) via a single blank line.

Comment: do NOT post links to images,  Rather copy and past the text directly into the question.

Comment: regarding: `char* array[x];`  What is the value contained in `x`?  If `x` is too small, then the code will overflow `array[]`, resulting in undefined behavior, which can lead to a seg fault event

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  It is not even a complete function.  How do you expect us to reproduce the problem if you haven't supplied the code.  Please post a [mcve]

Comment: the posted contents of the input file do not match the contents of the image referenced.  How do you expect us to help you when you did not post your actual input.

Comment: Well, thank you for your will to help me, but i already solved the problem. Im newbie at programming. I didn't post whole program (x was included as 500). Didn't also post FILE.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i've got it.
If i knew it was that simple...
All i had to do was to change those lines:

```
array[i]=Buffor;
printf("\n%s for %d", array[i], i);
```

To these:

```
array[i]=malloc(strlen(Buffor) + 1);\
strcpy(array[i], Buffor);
printf("\n%s for %d", array[i], i);
```

Comment: you could greatly simplify this 'answer' by making use of `strdup()`  In either case, remember to pass all those pointers to `free()` before exiting the program to avoid any memory leak.